# Recuperar los datos de un JSON en java

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Desde mi aplicación Java estoy llamando a un servicio REST el cual debe recuperar un JSON de este estilo:

```
"body": {
        "PERSONA": {
            "PERSONA": [
                {
                    "NOMBRE": "",
                    "APELLIDOS": "",
                    "DNI": "",
                    "EDAD": ""
                },
                {
                    "NOMBRE": "",
                    "APELLIDOS": "",
                    "DNI": "",
                    "EDAD": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo recuperar todos los datos para guardarlos en una clase DTO (si se puede), sé que una opción son JSONObject y JSONArray pero no se cómo puedo distinguir "PERSONA padre" de "PERSONA hijo" (son sólo uno ambos, no una lista en el JSON, el hijo tendrá un array con los datos).

Así llamo al servicio Rest, siendo PersonaBody el objeto de entrada para los parámetros de dicho servicio:

```
PersonaBody body = new PersonaBody();
body.setIdClie(idClieCess);
body.setTipo(tipoCont);
body.setMedio(medioCont);
        
final Call<PersonaResponse> call = REST_CLIENT.getUrlPersona(body);
Response<PersonaResponse> retrofitResponse = call.execute();
        
final int returnCode = retrofitResponse.code();
if(returnCode == 200) {
    log.info("[PersonaClient]  devolvio 200");
    final PersonaResponse PersonaResponse = retrofitResponse.body();
}
```

Cualquier duda o aclaración, decídmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Como todo en la programación tiene muchas opciones y puntos de vista para una solución, el problema que veo en tu pregunta es que no muestras código de cómo obtienes el JSON, edita tu respuesta y muestra un ejemplo de como realizas la llamada porque Spring ya tiene métodos para mapear el json pero dependerá de como llames el servicio para poder darte una solución.

Comment: Editado, espero que te sriva

Answer (score 0):

Lo tuyo más que nada es un problema de diseño. La estructura correcta debería ser esta ([copiar/pegar el JSON aquí si quieres analizarlo](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)):

```
{
   "body":{
      "Padre":{
         "NOMBRE":"",
         "APELLIDOS":"",
         "DNI":"",
         "EDAD":"",
         "Hijos":[
            {
               "NOMBRE":"",
               "APELLIDOS":"",
               "DNI":"",
               "EDAD":""
            },
            {
               "NOMBRE":"",
               "APELLIDOS":"",
               "DNI":"",
               "EDAD":""
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Tenemos:

1. Una propiedad `Padre`  con sus atributos normales de `Persona`, como `Nombre`, `Apellidos` etc.
2. Padre tiene una propiedad `Hijos` que es un array de objetos JSON (considerando que puede tener uno o más hijos).

Expresado en clases tendrías algo así:

**`Persona`**

```
public class Persona 
{

    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String dni;
    private int edad;

    public Persona (String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, int edad) 
    {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellidos=apellidos;
        this.dni=dni;
        this.edad=edad;
    }

    //...Otros métodos y geters y seters
}
```

**`Padre`**

```
public class Padre extends Persona 
{

    private ArrayList <Persona> Hijos;

    public Padre (String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, int edad, ArrayList<Persona> Hijos) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, dni, edad);
        this.Hijos=Hijos;
    }
    //...Otros métodos y geters y seters
}
```

Aquí no he creado una clase específica para `Hijo`, pero si hiciera falta la podrías crear, haciendo que extienda también de persona.

Con ese modelo podrás mapear el JSON sin ningún problema a tu modelo de datos y trabajar de forma ordenada. Si no normalizas se te hará un lío en el programa, por ejemplo cuando haya un padre con muchos hijos.

Para evitar problemas, considera poner las propiedades del JSON en minúscula.

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisarlo. El problema del JSON que no es mío, yo lo recibo así. Sólo es un "hijo" que contendrá un array

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes hacer utilizando Gson por ejemplo. Suponiendo que tienes tu DTO con los atributos correspondientes, puedes obtener la información del Array.
En este ejemplo la respuesta la recibimos y guardamos como String:

```
SoyUnDTO dto = new SoyUnDTO();
String response = retrofitResponse.body();
JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray persona = convertedObject.get("PERSONA").getAsJsonArray("PERSONA");
for(int i = 0; i < persona.size(); i++){
dto.setNombre(persona.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("NOMBRE").getAsString());
dto.setApellidos(persona.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("APELLIDOS").getAsString());

// HACER LO MISMO CON LOS OTROS ATRIBUTOS....
}
```